# Отправка почты с формы Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Знаний в Laravel пока не очень много, посему прошу помощи.
Требуется отправить данные с формы по почте. Причем отправка формы со страницы уже есть, нужно отправить форму на почту, только с другими параметрами.
Что сделал

1. Создал роут.

```
Route::post('/send', 'MailController@send')->name('mail.send');
Route::post('/send-mail', 'MailSetting@sendForm')->name('mail.send-mail');
```

Первый роут уже существующий, второй мой, в принципе ничем не отличаются, только почтовые адреса будут разные.
2) Пользуюсь классом уже для созданной формы app/Mail/MailSend.php

```
namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class MailSend extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public $mailData;

    public function __construct($mailData)
    {
        $this->mailData = $mailData;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->view('mail')
            ->from('info@my-site.ru')
            ->subject('Заявка')
            ->with($this->mailData);
    }
}
```

3. Создал шаблон blade моей формы

```
<noindex>
    <div class="main-form">
        <h3>Моя форма</h3>
        <p></p>
        <form method="POST" action="{{route('mail.send-mail')}}" accept-charset="UTF-8" class="my-form uk-form">
                    <div class="uk-margin">
                        <input class="uk-input" placeholder="Высота забора, м*" name="height" type="text">
                        <span class="error heightError"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="uk-margin">
                        <input class="uk-input" placeholder="Длина забора, м*" name="length" type="text">
                        <span class="error nameError"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="uk-margin">
                        <input class="uk-input" placeholder="Количество калиток, шт" name="numberofwicket" type="text">
                        <span class="error lengthError"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="uk-margin">
                        <input class="uk-input" placeholder="Количество ворот, шт" name="numberofgates" type="text">
                        
                    </div>
                    <div class="uk-margin">
                        <input class="uk-input" placeholder="Удалённость от МКАД, км" name="distance" type="text">
                        
                    </div>                   
                    <div class="uk-margin">
                        <input class="uk-input" placeholder="Имя" name="username" type="text">
                        <span class="error usernameError"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="uk-margin">
                        <input class="uk-input phone_number" placeholder="+7 (___) ___-__-__" name="userphone" type="text">
                        <span class="error userphoneError"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="uk-margin">
                        <input class="uk-input" placeholder="e-mail" name="usermail" type="text">
                        
                    </div>
                    <div class="uk-margin uk-grid uk-grid-small">
                        <div class="uk-width-small@s">
                            <input class="btn" value="Отправить" type="submit">
                        </div>
                        <div class="uk-width-expand@s mini_text">
                            Нажимая на кнопку, вы даете согласие на обработку своих персональных данных
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <input type="hidden" name="page" value="{{ URL::current() }}">
                </form>
    </div>
</noindex>
```

4. Создал контроллер для формы указанный в роуте.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests\MailRequest;
use App\Mail\MailSend;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

class MailSetting extends Controller
{

    public function sendForm(Request $request, CalcMailRequest $mailRequest)
    {
        $mailData = $request->all();
        // $mail = ['yshliu_lose@inbox.ru'];
        $mail = ['eliseev_denis_95@mail.ru'];
        Mail::to($mail)->send(new MailSend($mailData));
        return response()->json([
            'successful'=>"<div class='message'>Спасибо, за обращение! <br> Мы ответим Вам совсем скоро.</div>"
        ]);
    }
}
```

Дальше возможно я не прав, по примеру первой формы, создал файл запроса в папке Requests

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class CalcmailRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        switch($this->method())
        {
            case 'GET':
            case 'DELETE':
            {
                return [];
            }
            case 'POST':
            {
                return [
                    'height' => 'required',
                    'length' => 'required',
                    'numberofwicket' => 'nullable',
                    'numberofgates' => 'nullable',
                    'distance' => 'nullable',
                    'userphone' => 'required',
                    'userphone' => 'required',
                    'useremail' => 'nullable'
                ];
            }
            default:break;
        }
    }

    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            'height.required' => '* Укажите желаемую высоту забора!',
            'length.required' => '* Укажите желаемую длинну забора!',
            'userphone.required' => '* Вы не указали телефон!',
            'username.required' => '* Укажите Ваше имя!',
        ];
    }
}
```

5. Обновил font.js для вывода ошибок моей формы

```
if (document.querySelector(".my-form")) {
        var calcmainForm = document.querySelectorAll(".my-form");
        for(var k = 0; k < mainForm.length; k++ )
        {
            calcmainForm[k].onsubmit = function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var formClass = this;
                var params = '';
                if (formClass.elements['height']) params += '&height=' + formClass.elements['height'].value;
                if (formClass.elements['length']) params += '&length=' + formClass.elements['length'].value;
                if (formClass.elements['username']) params += '&username=' + formClass.elements['username'].value;
                if (formClass.elements['userphone']) params += '&userphone=' +  formClass.elements['userphone'].value;
                if (formClass.elements['useremail']) params += '&useremail=' + formClass.elements['useremail'].value;
                if (formClass.elements['page']) params += '&page=' + formClass.elements['page'].value;
                ajaxToServer(method, uri, params, token, function () {
                    if (this.successful !== undefined) {
                        formClass.innerHTML = this.successful;
                        ym(48261257, 'reachGoal', 'forma');
                    };

                    if (this.errors.height !== undefined) {
                        formClass.querySelector('.heightError').style = 'display:block';
                        formClass.querySelector('.heightError').innerHTML = this.errors.height;
                    } else {
                        formClass.querySelector('.heightError').style = 'display:none';
                    };

                    if (this.errors.length !== undefined) {
                        formClass.querySelector('.lengthError').style = 'display:block';
                        formClass.querySelector('.lengthError').innerHTML = this.errors.length;
                    } else {
                        formClass.querySelector('.lengthError').style = 'display:none';
                    };

                    if (this.errors.username !== undefined) {
                        formClass.querySelector('.usernameError').style = 'display:block';
                        formClass.querySelector('.usernameError').innerHTML = this.errors.username;
                    } else {
                        formClass.querySelector('.usernameError').style = 'display:none';
                    };
                    if (this.errors.userphone !== undefined) {
                        formClass.querySelector('.userphoneError').style = 'display:block';
                        formClass.querySelector('.userphoneError').innerHTML = this.errors.userphone;
                    } else {
                        formClass.querySelector('.userphoneError').style = 'display:none';
                    };
                    /*if (this.errors.useremail !== undefined) {
                        formClass.querySelector('.useremailError').style = 'display:block';
                        formClass.querySelector('.useremailError').innerHTML = this.errors.useremail;
                    } else {
                        formClass.querySelector('.useremailError').style = 'display:none';
                    };*/
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

Но при отправке формы выводит предупреждение: The page has expired due to inactivity.

Please refresh and try again.

P.S. Простите за большое количество кода и текста, но чтобы было полное представление об ошибке и кода скидываю все что есть. Уже много просмотрел документации, но понимания ошибки не приходит пока. Прошу вашей помощи.

Comment: Добавьте в форму `{{ csrf_field() }}`

Answer (score 1):

Вероятнее всего, ошибка из-за отсутсвия CSRF токена.

Достаточно добавить `@csrf` в любой строке вашей формы:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{route('mail.send-mail')}}" accept-charset="UTF-8" class="my-form uk-form">
                    @csrf
                    <div class="uk-margin">
                        <input class="uk-input" placeholder="Высота забора, м*" name="height" type="text">
                        <span class="error heightError"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="uk-margin">
                        <input class="uk-input" placeholder="Длина забора, м*" name="length" type="text">
                        <span class="error nameError"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="uk-margin">
                        <input class="uk-input" placeholder="Количество калиток, шт" name="numberofwicket" type="text">
                        <span class="error lengthError"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="uk-margin">
                        <input class="uk-input" placeholder="Количество ворот, шт" name="numberofgates" type="text">
                        
                    </div>
                    <div class="uk-margin">
                        <input class="uk-input" placeholder="Удалённость от МКАД, км" name="distance" type="text">
                        
                    </div>                   
                    <div class="uk-margin">
                        <input class="uk-input" placeholder="Имя" name="username" type="text">
                        <span class="error usernameError"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="uk-margin">
                        <input class="uk-input phone_number" placeholder="+7 (___) ___-__-__" name="userphone" type="text">
                        <span class="error userphoneError"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="uk-margin">
                        <input class="uk-input" placeholder="e-mail" name="usermail" type="text">
                        
                    </div>
                    <div class="uk-margin uk-grid uk-grid-small">
                        <div class="uk-width-small@s">
                            <input class="btn" value="Отправить" type="submit">
                        </div>
                        <div class="uk-width-expand@s mini_text">
                            Нажимая на кнопку, вы даете согласие на обработку своих персональных данных
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <input type="hidden" name="page" value="{{ URL::current() }}">
                </form>
```

Comment: Ааха, спасибо заработало, по крайней мере теперь отправляет POST на сервер. Теперь только ошибка в контроллере, скорее всего где то в Request ошибся.
В строке 
~~~
Mail::to($mail)->send(new MailSend($mailData));
~~~

Comment: Поделитесь сообщением об ошибке, возможно сможем решить проблему :)

Comment: Там было все намного проще, прочитал кучу информации, вроде бы настроил env. файл, файл mail.php с папке config поменял на стандартный, оказалось, что отправку блочил мой OpenServer, нужно было настроить почту gmail и разрешить сторонним устройствам принимать почту(в настройках gmail).

Comment: Аммм, да, только одной проблемки не усмотрел... Я создал отдельный файл Request для моей формы, что вроде бы как не совсем правильно. Читал что, если на странице больше чем одна форма, то для них можно создавать MessageBag, чтобы валидировать их по отдельности и выводить сообщения об ошибках разные. У меня сейчас совсем не выводит сообщения об ошибках, а просто не отрпавляет форму и обновляет страницу, если не все требуемые поля заполнены. Вот думаю как этого избежать

Comment: И как блин теперь все это в JS передать, который успешно рисует сообщение под полем для формы ранее созданной, но не рисует для моей формы... Я пока не пойму